# Internal Server Error 500 when performing REST call

Tags: nest-api

I'm attempting to test my client app, which has worked fine in the past. Over the last day, I've noticed calls to

```
https://developer-api.nest.com/?auth=c.XXX...
```

have returned 307 redirects to:

```
https://firebase-apiserver05-tah01-iad01.dapi.production.nest.com:9553/?auth=c.XXX...
```

Which I understand is normal to see. However, calling that is returning 500 Internal Server error responses. Using `curl -v` to test, I don't see any SSL errors or other negotiation issues that could cause the response I am seeing. Using an invalid token does immediately return the expected 401 error.

I have tried to create a new test client app and go through the process to get a new token. It all works normally up to the call for data.

Curious if anyone else has seen this issue where the best place to report it?

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting I found another question/answer regarding developer accounts and virtual devices. Sure enough, creating a new developer account and adding devices there works fine.

Still trying to understand why I am getting 500 errors instead of something more descriptive in the 4xx range.

Comment: Yes, quite annoying. I reached out to Nest and they weren't really sure what was going on. I assume it is an automatic block if you use the API too much. I found it was dropped after 2 days.